# Is it allowed to have multi service in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am pretty newbie in Helm and would like to know, if it is allowed to have multi services in service.yaml file like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "keycloak.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "keycloak.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "keycloak.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "keycloak.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "keycloak.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, are you facing any issue?

A cleaner way is to use two different files service-a.yaml and service-b.yaml

Note: Better not to have both the services with the same name.

Comment: You have mentioned `two different files service-a.yaml and service-b.yaml`, then after include into `service.yaml`?

Comment: you don't have to do any includes, helm renders/applies all the yaml files inside templates folder.

Comment: of course, an exception would be any file starting with an `_` helm doesn't render/apply them https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-partials-and-template-includes

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Sure refer: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus/templates

Comment: you see many service files like https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/templates/node-exporter-service.yaml and https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus/templates/alertmanager-service.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple services defined in one file by using a List kind

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: {{ .Values.appName }}{{ .Values.nameSuffix }}
    namespace: {{ .Values.projectNamespace }}
    labels:
      app: {{ .Values.appName }}
      owner: {{ .Values.ownerName }}
      project: {{ .Values.projectName }}
  spec:
    ports:
      - name: 8082-tcp
        port: 8082
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8082
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: {{ .Values.appName }}{{ .Values.nameSuffix }}
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: {{ .Values.appName }}
    namespace: {{ .Values.projectNamespace }}
    labels:
      app: {{ .Values.appName }}
      owner: {{ .Values.ownerName }}
      project: {{ .Values.projectName }}
  spec:
    ports:
      - name: 8082-tcp
        port: 8082
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 8082
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: {{ .Values.appName }}{{ .Values.nameSuffix }}
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```